# Run two apps on one heroku domain

Tags: heroku

I have two apps, one is a react app being served on a node server (front end). Another one is a Spring boot app (backend that provides bunch of REST API endpoints). They live on two different github repos.

Is there a way to configure heroku to serve both of them (they run on different ports) on one domain?

Right now, I have the java spring boot app being served on one heroku domain, I want the second react project to build and run on the same domain. Any idea ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I remember it was not possible, I'm not sure though. I decided to run one server at the end.